# What is the difference between a word and a short?

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I've tried doing my due diligence here, and I'm not sure if the systems register affects how big a word can be? but from a quick google, it seems that the definitive answer is that a word is 2 bytes(16 bits?) of data. To my knowledge, a short is also 16 bits of data.

Is the difference literally that a word is 2 bytes and a short is 16 bits (00000000 00000000 vs 0000000000000000), why do we have two types of data for the same(well at least extremely similar) datatype?

Is the difference more nuanced, like an OS level thing, similar to why Microsoft names their bool's BOOL, etc.?

Any light shed is appreciated thanks :) even better is reference material, since its really hard to google these topics without getting short stories as my search results *grumble*.

yes haha WORD and DWORD are the types I'm referring to, and were working on an embedded controller running WINCE13.

Comment: Are you talking about the c++ type short, vs the concept of a computer word? In that case the answer is that there is no direct correlation between the to.

Comment: You mentioned Microsoft and their definition, is that the WORD and DWORD that you're using?

Comment: You realize that a `double`, `int64_t`, `uint64_t`, and quite a few others are all 8 bytes, right? Data types are about a lot more than their size. And as was said, you're comparing apples and something that has no bearing on apples whatsoever. Unless you're talking about a MS-specific type, in which case you need to be specific and explicit when asking questions because reading minds isn't a thing.

Comment: types do not have to be different to be useful as distinct types. A quirky example is `char`. `char` is either signed or unsigned, so on the hardware level it is either the same as `unsigned char` or the same as `signed char`, nevertheless `char` is a distinct type, it is neither the same type as `signed char` nor `unsigned char`.

Comment: @harold - yes haha WORD and DWORD are the types I'm referring to, and were working on an embedded controller running WINCE13.

Comment: @Send_Help ... ok, and you thought that level of information was unnecessary?

Comment: Microsoft created these (WORD, BOOL, DWORD .. ) decades ago to have fixed sized types that they use in the windows api. Some of these were created before `c` or `c++` had fixed size types.

Comment: The best you can do is to search the header files for the definition of WORD and DWORD.  Many OS, and 3rd party libraries define the term.  There is no standard as to the range or byte size of WORD or DWORD.

Answer (score 3):

> it seems that the definitive answer is that a word is 2 bytes(16 bits?) of data.

whatever you googled, that's wrong.

"Word" is a bit of a contextual term, but in the context of data type sizes, it usually refers to the default size of integer registers, or that of a pointer.

So, on the machine you've wrote that question on, it's probably 32 bit, maybe 64 bit, depending on who you ask. Certainly not 2 byte like short.

On an 8bit microcontroller, it'd be 8 bit. On 16 bit machine, a machine word would be 16bit.

All in all, word is very ambiguous a term, and anybody who actually wants to specify a length will use a specifier like "in this SSE register, we group four 32 bit words to a 128 bit word".

---

with your late information:

> yes haha WORD and DWORD are the types I'm referring to, and were working on an embedded controller running WINCE13.

Then that's well-documented in the *context* of windows development. `WORD` is not the same as "a word", but a specific, microsoft-invented `typedef`, which might actually have a specific length.

Hint: Microsoft has stopped maintaining WindowsCE, and even the long-term paid support ends October 2023. Please migrate to a different platform, should you not wish to build an obsolete system from the start. You must especially never connect such a system to the internet – Microsoft will *not* provide further security updates.

Comment: yikes :O how many bits are supposed to be in a WORD?

Ahh nice, the edit helps clear thing up a bit :P

Comment: @Send_Help please see my updated answer.

Comment: any particula reason you write it "WORD"? That sounds like it comes from some context that you're forgetting to mention. And again, context is important (for *any meaning* of *anything* in language, not only here)

Comment: @Send_Help Why do you need to know? If you want to store values of a specific range, use fixed sized integer types such as `uint32_t`. If you need to know about the properties of a type def for an integral type, you'll probably be able to do everything you need using `sizeof()` and/or `std::numeric_limits`...